# How to debug fluent APIs?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, fluent-interface

Fluent APIs are awesome. They give concise and readable code.
But it is a severe pain when something works as not expected.

Are there any ways to see the intermediate results of the method calls chain in VS? May be some add-ins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since VS 2012 is is now possible to see returned results of methods in a chain.
See autos window.